# Is having a ubiquitous base object an anti pattern?

Tags: anti-patterns, oop

I remember seeing a debate about this somewhere, and am currently considering removing a base object that every business object, in a system I'm working on, inherits from. It contains a few properties, some database logic, and some constructor logic.

Is this an anti pattern, or is the jury still out? Would it be better to have a base contract to inherit from, which would require a certain amount of boilerplate coding to be done in each object?

**EDIT**: I do like dsimcha and feel it reflects very well on the issue, I am still happy to hear any further answers

Comment: I think this largely depends on your situation and whose propaganda you are interested in following.

Comment: Too true, still I'm trying to get a feel for the debate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard rule of thumb is to use inheritance only to provide flexibility for users of a class through polymorphism, and use composition if you want to reuse code from other classes.  However, as long as you're not violating the [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) it's probably not too bad.  Writing tons of boilerplate is inherently a bad thing, too, since it obscures the parts of your code where the real action is happening and is anti-DRY.  If you are violating the Liskov Substitution Principle, though, then absolutely this is a bad idea.

Comment: Very good point - Liskov does appear to be a driving factor in the argument

Answer (score 2):

> I also would like to understand what problems I may encounter, or should be aware of

A potential problem is if you use multiple inheritance: your subclass then inherits two instances of the 'Eve' classes ... which is why C++ supports so-called virtual inheritance.

It's a frequently-used idiom: for example in .Net everything derives from `System.Object` ... and/or, all COM objects implement the IQueryInterface interface.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is an anti-pattern in a vacuum.  Is your 'Eve class' causing you problems?  What benefits do you expect to realize from removing it?  Asking whether it's on [some standard list of anti-patterns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern) only helps if it aids in identifying actual issues.

Comment: true, but I also would like to understand what problems I may encounter, or should be aware of